# Extra characters pushed in while rendering template

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I attempted to pass HTML code while rendering a jade template. Although I got the desired HTML code rendered, there are additional Angular Brackets and HTML code that gets rendered.

I want this functionality to work so that I can have my jade templates I use to send emails with, be viewed on the UI.

I have stripped down all additional code and made it pretty straight forward.

***view_temp.jade***

```
html
   body
      .container
         #{srcStr}
```

***index.js***

```
router.get('/view', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('view_temp', {srcStr: '<h3>test</h3>'});
});
```

***view-source:hxxp://localhost:3000/view***

```
<html><body><div class="container"><<h3>test</h3>></<h3>test</h3>></div></body></html>
```

I would like to understand why the output has been rendered like this **`<<h3>test</h3>></<h3>test</h3>>`**

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Replace the following code,

```
html
   body
      .container
         #{srcStr}
```

to

```
html
   body
      .container !{srcStr}
```

The output will be **`<h1>abc</h1>`**

Comment: Thanks. But the text in the container div is HTML Encoded. I want it to as is, so that i can execute HTML code in it. This is what I have now in **page-source**: `<div class="container">&lt;h3&gt;test&lt;/h3&gt;</div>`

Answer (score 2):

To explain @chetan's answer, According to the documentation,

> By default, text at the start of a line (or after only white space) represents an html tag. Indented tags are nested, creating the tree like structure of html.

So in your case, `<h3>test</h3>` is treated as tag.

```
<*<h3>test</h3>*> </*<h3>test</h3>*>
```

So, you instead of putting the `#{srcStr}` in new line, you should put the `#{srcStr}` in the same line of `.container`. And instead of using `#{..}` you can use the **unsafe** `!{..}` to render html as-is.

```
html
   body
      .container !{srcStr}
```